# Kotlin module sources not packaged in aar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-library, aar

I'm building an Android library (aar) in Java.
I want to add a Kotlin module to it. It works great when developing but the sources of the module are missing from the .aar file so it crushes at runtime in the application with `FileNotFoundException`.

The main module `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: "maven-publish"

...

android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':kotlinModule')
    ....
}
```

Thre `build.gradle` of the module is:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
```

I've tried to add a source set but apparently you can't add source sets from outside your module folder.
I've tried to copy the `kotlinModule.jar` file into `libs` folder but then I need to rebuild every time I make a change to the module.
How can I make the sources of the module to be bundled into the .aar file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add **kotlinModule.aar** file then you need to add some configuration in your Gradle config inside your **android** tag

```
android {
        repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
            jcenter()
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
}
```

**Also, add your .aar file name in your Gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {    
     implementation name: 'kotlinModule', ext: 'aar'        
}
```

Comment: I already answered this in the question: "I've tried to copy the kotlinModule.jar file into libs folder but then I need to rebuild every time I make a change to the module."